# How to reference related model's fields in a form helper tied to a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Complete beginner to Rails here:

In Rails:

I have a Model Post, which hasmany Tags. When creating a new Post, I want the user to be able to create up to 5 tags that are tied to the Post.

I set up the form to create a new Post like this:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %><br/>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
   </div>
   ... Some more of these
   <div class="field">   <!-- I want this to refer to the name attribute of a Tag model-->
      <%= f.label :tag_name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :tag_name %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

Obviously, this doesn't work since the Post class does not have a tag_name attribute. What's the proper way to do this?

Assume that Tag is an aggregation table that has the following fields:

```
id: primary key
post_id: foreign key to Post's primary key
name: name of the tag
```

Comment: Have you looked into using nested_attributes_for? That might get you heading down the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1).

Basically, you need [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and then [fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for).

Answer (score 2):

Try using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :post_id
  belongs_to :post
end
```

On your form, along with the attributes for Post, use :

```
<% f.fields_for :tag, @post.address do |builder| %>
   <p>
     <%= builder.text_field :post_id %>
   <p>
<% end %>
```

Something like that. Good luck coding.